# Trouble understanding __attribute__ tag

Tags: c++, gcc

```
extern "C" int asnprintf (char **ret, size_t max_sz, const char *format, ...)
    __attribute__ ((format (printf, 3, 4)));
```

Reading the source code of nmap I came accross this function declaration and I am having troubles understanding it.

Here is what [this webpage](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/gnu-c-attributes.html) says about it:

Based on

```
__attribute__((format(printf, m, n)));
```

> The (m) is the number of the "format string" parameter, and (n) is the number of the first variadic parameter.

I don't understand what is he refering to when saying "format string"; are they just the arguments which affects the behaviour of the function?

Also, what is the number of the first variadic parameter? In all the examples I have seen it is always one more than `m`, is this always true? Could you give a practical example where is not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extern "C" int asnprintf (char **ret, size_t max_sz, const char *format, ...)
                               ^1              ^2               ^3        ^4
```

> I don't understand what is he refering to when saying "format string"; are they just the arguments which affects the behaviour of the function?

The format string is the one you generally find in `printf` for example, like `"%0.3f %s"` ecc. and of course the function will act accordingly.

> Also, what is the number of the first variadic parameter? In all the examples I have seen it is always one more than m, is this always true? Could you give a practical example where is not?

In that case, `m = 3` and `n = 4`, but it need not be so. Let's say you have

```
int blablabla(const void *const data, const char *format, int data, ...)
```

then `m = 2` and `n = 4`.

Comment: Not variadic  - type check parameter start. You do not need it for variable number of parameters. ....f functions have compiler built in type check in gcc - and that is the reason for this attribute - to be able to use this built feature in the programmers functions. But remeber - it makes your code not portable.

Comment: @PeterJ: I have nowhere said it has to be the place of the variadic argument in the list. Yet this is true _unless_ you have a `%d` in `format` and so `data` is always included.

Comment: Your answer is not correct. To be honest - it is far from being correct, or maybe is very imprecise .

Comment: @PeterJ: If you can't point out what's wrong (if any), unfortunately I can't do anything but ignoring your objections.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the gcc manual:

> The format attribute specifies that a function takes printf, scanf,
>   strftime or strfmon style arguments which should be type-checked
>   against a format string.
>
> format (archetype, string-index, first-to-check)
>
> The parameter archetype determines how the format string is
>   interpreted, and should be printf, scanf, strftime or strfmon. (You
>   can also use **printf**, **scanf**, **strftime** or **strfmon**.) The
>   parameter string-index specifies which argument is the format string
>   argument (starting from 1), while first-to-check is the number of the
>   first argument to check against the format string. For functions where
>   the arguments are not available to be checked (such as vprintf),
>   specify the third parameter as zero. In this case the compiler only
>   checks the format string for consistency. For strftime formats, the
>   third parameter is required to be zero. Since non-static C++ methods
>   have an implicit this argument, the arguments of such methods should
>   be counted from two, not one, when giving values for string-index and
>   first-to-check.

Comment: What happens when inputs are not variadic? Does it create a problem?

Comment: I did not try. have no idea